# OpenCSV how to get malformed line with CsvToBeanBuilder

Tags: java, opencsv

we are using OpenCSV java library 5.7.0 and we are using the following piece of code to create the builder and then read the CSV line by line:

```
        CsvToBean<Protocollo> cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
         .withType(Bean.class)
         .withSeparator(',')
         .withSkipLines(1)
         .build();
        
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Bean b = it.next();
        }
```

but then I noticed if any malformed line happens then I got an exception which is not catched in my code. I would like to catch this kind of exception and log it accordingly.

many thanks

Comment: Did you check [this](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBean.html#setThrowExceptions-boolean-) out?

Comment: `then I got an exception which is not caught in my code` - then just catch it, what's the problem with it? `try { ... } catch (...) { ... }`?

Comment: @ursa the exception is not thrown to the user code so I can't simply catch it.

Comment: @g00se the malformed exception is an IOException so I can't use CsvExceptionHandler because it handles CsvException which does not extend IOException

Comment: I think we need to see a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) We also need to know what input you're supplying that's giving you an `IOException`